# Customising a slider to add captions over

Tags: html, css, slider

Hi I currently have a nice responsive slider setup but the captions are pushed below with a 'Find out more' button also below.

I just wondered if anyone can see how to adjust this so the button and text is over the images revolving round please?

http://newsite.poppletoncentre.org.uk/index.php?id=4

Comment: A JsFiddle would be much better than a link to your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this CSS to container

```
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 10;
```